# Is the public IP address of a client a good security token?

Tags: security, web-applications, ip

My web-app has this *secret place* only some people are allowed to use. When a user logs in to my secret place, I try gather as much information from them as I can, concatenate it, hash it, and send it as a cookie. Information such as : User Agent, IP Adress, Users's password, plus a few more...

When a client requests anything, I regenerate all those things, hash them, and compare them to the cookie the clients sends me.

If some guy steals the cookies, they will probably have different User-Agents from the guy who legally logged in, and the hashes wont match, not letting him in.

If some older-wiser-guy fakes all the http headers, i'll see the IP address mismatch and the hash wont match.. not letting him in.

There is where my problem resides, what should I do if my legally logged in client loses internet connectivity and the re-establishes it with another IP Adress as his/her ISP leases dynamic IP's. My current algorithm will say "Aha ! This is an attacker ! Close this session !".

This secret place is better if not disrupted for valid users, and since, for some reason internet connectivity has been intermittent the last couple of weeks, my users find uncomfortable the fact that the application requires them to re-login every time their IP changes.

Should I discard the IP validation ?

Comment: **and then re-establishes it with another IP Address as ISP leases dynamic IP**: So the answer is IP is not a good key.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to do what the key files in an ssh session do: keep the user from having to type a password. The thing about the ssh keys, is that they can't be maliciously retrieved by somene else  over the network Since it's a challenge-response, they aren't prone to man-in-the-middle attacks. Can't you set cookies so no-one else can get them off the network?

Comment: @atreys So i just should grant access to any IP ? Maybe try to geolocate IP's, and then compare those, any ideas ?

Comment: Another question might get you the answer you want: Q: how do you do ssh key style authentication over https?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Trying to impose security by obscurity or security by complexity is often more prone to exploitation than simple, well-understood security measures.**

You have correctly identified that fixing a session to an IP can be a detriment to user experience. You have to decide whether this inconvenience(especially for TOR or other anonymization and mobile network users) is worth the additional security.

Bear in mind that an attacker who can intercept communication between your server and the client can likely also communicate with the client's IP address. It is trivial if he's in the client's LAN, and otherwise still simple. So in essence, you're defending against the nearly-empty set of attackers who are totally incompetent and yet can intercept network traffic in relatively secure high-bandwidth networks (your local installation or core internet routers).

If security is really such an issue - and it's usually not unless you're running a bank, large company, or military-ish organization - better use SSL, check your website for common vulnerabilities, and secure client computers.

Answer (score 1):

No.  IP address is not a good security token since it can be [spoofed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing).

It can be used as one signal to indicate attempted impersonation, but as you noted it is not always a perfect indicator since IPs are not stable.  They tend to change as users move from one wireless gateway to another, move from wired connection to wireless, change proxy settings as they tunnel into an intranet, etc.

It might also discriminate against anyone trying to use [tor](http://www.torproject.org/) or other secure browsing schemes.